# merging the content of a directory using cmd shell

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-4.0

I want to merge all the files in a directory into one. However I tried several versions but none of them seem to work. I am getting an error saying that the file was not found. Here is what I was trying:

```
        String outputFile = this.outputTxt.Text;
        String inputFolder = this.inputTxt.Text;
        String files = "";
        String command;
        foreach (String f in Directory.GetFiles(inputFolder))
        {
            files += f+"+";
        }
        files = files.Substring(0, files.Length - 1);
        command = files + " " + outputFile;

        Process.Start("copy",command);
```

sample of what I want to obtain: 
copy a.txt+b.txt+c.txt+d.txt output.txt

And the error I get is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: *what* are you trying to do? why are you concating file names with a `+`?

Comment: @Shai: It's a way to concatenate files together using `copy fileA + fileB + ...fileN`

Comment: Do any of the files have a space in their name, you may need to quote the file names.

Comment: Have you attached with a debugger to look at what the actual command text is you are passing in?

Comment: yes; this is a sample of call with the actual arguments: Process.Start("copy", "D:\\input\\PSA3008420338.usg D:\\input.txt");

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown? Is it in the snippet you posted here or later in the code?

Comment: it is on the last line of the snipped. @ Process.Start ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try starting cmd rather than "start" with process.

```
Process.Start("cmd", "copy " + command);
```

'copy' is a command in the command prompt, aliased to... something, and not an actual file itself that windows knows how to run (outside of the command prompt).

There are properties of the Process class that you can use to suppress the window that the shell pops up if you don't want it on the screen while the program is running.

Comment: I believe you are correct... this is how I always do it. Didn't clue in that he was doing it the other way (time for a coffee!). +1

Answer (score 4):

Should you not be using `command` instead of `files` for your second parameter to `Process.Start`?

```
Process.Start("copy", command);
```

UPDATE:

Ok, so it was a typo. How about your inputFolder text? Is it using double back-slashes for the directories (escaping the back-slashes)? As in all `\` characters should be `\\`.

Comment: command string looks like: "D:\\input\\PSA3008420338.usg D:\\input.txt"

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei: So you final command string is: `copy D:\\inputPSA3008420338.usg D:\\input.txt` (when you include the actual copy process)?

Comment: @CoroveiAndrei: What happens if you type in a command shell manually?

Answer (score 2):

You need to call cmd.exe with the copy command and your arguments (as was mentioned by @Servy). Here is a cleaned up version of your code to do what you need:

```
    String outputFile = this.outputTxt.Text;
    String inputFolder = this.inputTxt.Text;
    StringBuilder files = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (String f in Directory.EnumerateFiles(inputFolder))
    {
        files.Append(f).Append("+");
    }
    files = files.Remove(file.Length-1, 1); // Remove trailing plus
    files.Append(" ").Append(outputFile);      

    using (var proc = Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C copy " + files.ToString()))
    {
        proc.WaitForExit();
    }
```

You need to dispose of the Process (thus the using statement) and since you are concatenating a lot of strings (potentially a lot of strings anyway), you should use a StringBuilder.